# SSIS connection manager can not connect to sql server using Native OLEDB Provider

Tags: ssis, oledbconnection

Why would call from SSIS to connect to database server using OLEDB Provider (such as Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0) fails to make a connection? I get error: Client Unable to establish connection. Hresult: 0x80004005. However I do not get error when same package makes a connection to same database using ".Net Provider\SqlClient Data Provider"

Comment: Can you please give more info (update your question), like the following: 1. Does it happen on the server or in visual studio? 2. (if it's server) What do you use to run the package on the server? 3. (If's it local) What debug mode do you use x86 or x 64? Furthermore, I think, you have to have something else in your log beside this message.

Comment: Connection sting and firewall related issue please share more detail to get answer

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself